# Mostrar a descrição do item apenas quando for igual senão aparecer como “ null ” ou “ Sem Descrição ”

Tags: sql-server

No SqlServer, preciso que apareça na coluna Descrição apenas os valores que tenham todos os valores iguais agrupados em group by, senão mostrar como `null` ou `Sem Descrição`, quando tiver uma descrição diferente como no item `00500373`.

Exemplo abaixo

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Deverá aparecer assim:

```
Item = 00500237 Descricao = AJUSTE DE ESTOQUE

Item = 00500373 Descricao = Null
```

Answer (score 0):

Creio que algo do tipo:

```
SELECT Item, 
       (CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sua_tabela aux WHERE aux.Item = sua_tabela.Item AND aux.Descricao <> sua_tabela.Descricao)
             THEN NULL
             ELSE aux.Descricao
        END) AS Descricao 
FROM sua_tabela
```

possa atende-lo.
Poste uma definição da tabela, com os respectivos INSERTs, para que possa ser testado.